# How to convert the minSdkVersion from latest minSdkVersion

Tags: android, version

In my application i am using

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"
     />
```

I want to run my `application android:minSdkVersion="8"`.But i am using `ActionBar` and `Fragment` and using lot of latest supported versions.So how to convert the above into lowest version.. and what type of jar file will be added please help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Fragment` from the support package. For the ActionBar you can use `ActionBarSherlock`. [Here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) you can find `ActionBarSherlock`

Comment: but i completed my project using actionbar.so how i am changing this i think i add some jar file so please tell that jar file...

Comment: you have to do some work. You have to add sherlock and change all  the getActionBar with getSupportActionBar, for instance